# php GD2 lib uncommented, but still doesn't work!

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini, gd

i have installed Apache/2.2.17 (Win64) PHP/5.2.8-x64 . i need GD2 lib... so i went to php.ini, uncomment php_gd2.dll and restarded server. nothing! gd lib doesn't work! help!

Comment: you did restart the apache server right?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PHP is built with GD support.
Create a standard phpinfo() file and see if libgd if figuring there. If not, you probably will have to rebuild your PHP.

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: Oops!.. Windows(R)... Not so shure with my answer.

Comment: dosen't work...

Comment: But libGD is present in this sample page ouput, right? The code, I posted in the answer is the code for a test php.page  Create the page, point your browser to it and find "libgd" on the resulting page. Or I misunderstood your comment.